# How many trees, not necessarily spanning, are there with exactly m edges and n vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

I've been struggling with this combinatorical question and got very confused:

Given $n$ vertices: $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$, in how many ways can a tree be assembled upon them, not necessarily spanning, so that it will have exactly m edges?

so, my first thought was that $m=n-1$  necessarily, because we are dealing with a tree here and it has to have $n-1$ edges.
Second, how come Cayley theorem doesn't provide a direct solution to that question, and it's simply $n^{n-2}$?

EDIT: The question is how many forests with n vertices are there with m edges

Comment: "not necessarily spanning"

Comment: yes, that's what I don't understand how it affects my problem, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Cayley's formula is for spanning trees on $n$ labeled vertices. I agree that your question is a bit confusing though. Should it say "*forests*"?

Comment: Well, that's what was asked in the question...

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering is if $m<n-1$, then are you supposed to "assemble" a tree just on some subset of $m+1$ vertices (and leave the other vertices isolated)?

Comment: I thought about that as well, but then not all of the vertices would make a tree...

Comment: I know, that's why I asked if it should say "forests". Where does this problem come from? If it's from a class, you should go ask the instructor to clarify.

Comment: I checked it out and it turns out that it doesn't have to be connected, meaning: if {v1,v2} is connectd while the remaining n-2 vertices are not - it's a legal possibility.

Comment: Ok so choose $m+1$ vertices, and then apply Cayley's formula.